Lambda Nodejs Event Listener
My objective is to run my lambda function in NodeJS to retrieve the NoIP's stored IP address with the hostname and username and password, using the "no-ip" nodejs library.
Here is my code: Sorry need to omit the hostname, user and pass value.
import NoIP from "no-ip";

async function noIPService() {

    const noIP = new NoIP({
        hostname: "",
        user: "",
        pass: ""
    });
    noIP.start();

    noIP.on("success", (isChanged, ip) => { console.log("ip: ", ip); return ip; });
    noIP.stop();
}

export const handler = async (event) => {
    var result = await noIPService();
    console.log("result: ", result);
}

I try to await for the success event. But somehow the lambda run through it without waiting for the success event to be triggered. So is there a way to listen to the success event before executing the rest of the code? Please advice

What is your intention using no-ip in a short-lived Lambda function? And why do you stop it almost immediately after starting it?

my intention is to get the IP Address from the no-ip to modify my AWS Customer Gateway as my device does not support dynamic ip which requires BGN. There is no intention to run continuously. If there is any other method to get the information, please share with me.

Your noIPService function makes a call that will yield a result asynchronously but your code, as written, does not correctly wait for that asynchronous callback to happen.
One way to correct it is as follows, wrapping the asynchronous callback in a promise:
import NoIP from "no-ip";

async function noIPService() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const noIP = new NoIP({
            hostname: "xxx",
            user: "yyy",
            pass: "zzz"
        });

        noIP.start();

        noIP.on("success", (isChanged, ip) => {
            console.log("ip: ", ip);
            noIP.stop();
            resolve(ip); 
        });

        noIP.on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            noIP.stop();
            reject(err); 
        });
    });

}

export const handler = async (event) => {
    const result = await noIPService();
    console.log("result: ", result);
}

